# Creating PDF from HTML with Dynamic Header and Footer Using AJAX - PDF Generation Interrupted After File Upload

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation

I have a problem creating pdf.
scenario: I create pdf from html. I need to dynamically create separate HTML for my footer and header areas.
Problem: After receiving my main HTML content according to my draft via ajax request, I download the file on the server for the footer. I open the file I downloaded and change the text in it with Replace. Then I upload it to the folder I specified with a new name. After the file is uploaded to the folder, it refreshes the page and my pdf creation process is interrupted.
I will be giving you my js codes and methods in the Controller below. What solution should I implement?
**The line where the problem occurs:** `await System.IO.File.WriteAllTextAsync(footerFilePath, footerContent);`
**js codes:**

```
function loadTemplateContent(pdfTemplateID) {

    var fDocumentGUID = $('#documentGUID').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/_Ajax/GetPDFTemplateContent',
        data: { pdfTemplateID: pdfTemplateID, fDocumentGUID: fDocumentGUID },
        success: function (data) {
            originalContent = data;
            CKEDITOR.instances['TemplateContent'].setData(data);
            //footerContent = data.footer;
        }

    });
}
```

**method:**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPDFTemplateContent(int pdfTemplateID, Guid? fDocumentGUID)
{
    var template = await _serviceManager.PDFTemplates.GetByIdAsync(pdfTemplateID);
    if (template == null)
    {
        return Json(string.Empty);
        //return Json(new { header = string.Empty, content = string.Empty, footer = string.Empty });
    }
    string content = template.TemplateContent;
    string footerContent = string.Empty;

    if (fDocumentGUID.HasValue)
    {
        var fDocument = await _serviceManager.FDocuments.GetEntityAsync(a => a.GUID == fDocumentGUID.Value);
        if (fDocument != null)
        {
            var selectedDataVW = await _serviceManager.VW_FDocuments.GetEntityAsync(a => a.GUID == fDocumentGUID.Value);

            var customerAdress = _serviceManager.Customers.GetValue(a => a.GUID == selectedDataVW.CustomerGUID, "Adress");
            var responsibleMember = await _serviceManager.VW_Members.GetEntityAsync(a => a.MemberID == selectedDataVW.ResponsibleMemberID);
            var obligatoryMemberNames = await _MemberDataService.GetMemberIDsWithNamesAndTypes(fDocument.ObligatoryMemberIDs, false);
            var (infoMemberNames, infoMemberTypeNames) = await _MemberDataService.GetMemberIDsWithNamesAndTypes(fDocument.InfoMemberIDs, true);


            content = content.Replace("$$FDocNo$$", selectedDataVW.FDocNo);
            content = content.Replace("$$FDocDate$$", selectedDataVW.FDocDate.ToShortDateString());

            content = content.Replace("$$CustomerName$$", selectedDataVW.CustomerName);
            content = content.Replace("$$CustomerAdress$$", customerAdress);

            content = content.Replace("$$ResponsibleMember$$", responsibleMember.NameSurname);
            content = content.Replace("$$ResponsibleMemberTitle$$", responsibleMember.MemberTypeName);

            content = content.Replace("$$InfoMember$$", infoMemberNames);
            content = content.Replace("$$InfoMemberTitle$$", infoMemberTypeNames);

            content = content.Replace("$$ToplantiyaKatilanlar$$", obligatoryMemberNames.MemberNameSurname);
        }
    }

    //footer
    string footerUrl = $"https://tkba.tdub.org.tr/lib/Templates/{template.FooterText}";
    footerContent = await _PdfService.DownloadContent(footerUrl);
    string formattedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
    var allowedFooters = new List<string> { "Footer_1.html", "Footer_3.html" };
    if (allowedFooters.Contains(template.FooterText))
    {
        var FooterFileName = $"{template.FooterText}-{formattedDate}.html";
        string footerFilePath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "images/Uploads", FooterFileName);

        var fDocument = await _serviceManager.FDocuments.GetEntityAsync(a => a.GUID == fDocumentGUID.Value);
        var (infoMemberNames, infoMemberTypeNames) = await _MemberDataService.GetMemberIDsWithNamesAndTypes(fDocument.InfoMemberIDs, true);

        footerContent = footerContent.Replace("$$InfoMember$$", infoMemberNames);
        footerContent = footerContent.Replace("$$InfoMemberTitle$$", infoMemberTypeNames);

        await System.IO.File.WriteAllTextAsync(footerFilePath, footerContent);
        //footerContent = FooterFileName;
    }

    //footer


    //return Json(new { success = true, content = content, footer = footerContent });
    return Json(content);
}
```

When I select one of the drafts that come with the select list, the content of the relevant draft will be loaded, then I will download the footer field of the draft from the url on the server and replace the relevant fields. Afterwards, I want to upload the current footer to the folder. After uploading to the folder, I want to get the name of the current footer here and continue my pdf creation method.
my problem; After creating and uploading the file, it refreshes the page. In this way, I cannot create my html content as pdf.

**solved: When hot-reload is on, the page refreshes on file uploads. It was solved by turning off this feature from vs studio.**

Comment: I removed the `html` tag and added the `c#` tag. I think that will get you a better audience for your question.